# How to drill Down uitableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've seen a tutorial about how to create a drill down table view and would like to know how to do the same, but instead of a `UITableViewController` I have a `UIViewController`.
Currently I have 2 TableViews in my ViewController. The first shows the data and the second is used for filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem writing an app that used multiple table views.  Are you having trouble getting the segues working?  I had the same problem, and used the following segue code within my uitableviewcontroller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
TypeTableViewController *nextController = segue.destinationViewController;
NSIndexPath *idx = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
nextController.detailLocation = [[self.tableData objectAtIndex: idx.row] objectForKey: @"location"];
nextController.detailType = [[self.tableData objectAtIndex: idx.row] objectForKey: @"type"];

NSLog(@"This is the first attached location: %@",[[self.tableData objectAtIndex: idx.row] objectForKey: @"location"]);
}
```

Is this where your problem lies or is it some other location within trying to get the data to filter?

Comment: I'm still using xib's so is there another of doing this? I'm still at the point of how to show the data as soon as a row is clicked. Has this to be done in DidSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: This is what I did to make everything work the way it should `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"filterCity" sender:self];
}`

Comment: For more information check out my [Github Repository](https://github.com/scromlish/PCF-APP-IOS)

Comment: I wrote before that I'm using xibs and no storyboard or is it that i can use this code even if I'm not using storyboard? If so what should "filter city" be (a xib, class, view)?

Comment: I now did this in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:
`SortViewController *nextController = [[SortViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        NSMutableArray *objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Name", @"City", nil];
nextController.title = @"Sort";
[nextController setRows:objects];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextController animated:YES];
[FilterView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];`
But the lower TableView wont drill down. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know because I have my app set up to use segues and storyboards.  I would re-ask the question or search for your specific problem elsewhere on StackOverflow.